# Convert lists inside a list to a character vector

Tags: r, list, vector

I need `b` **to be a list** but elements in `b` should be a character vector

```
a <- list('foo bar','foobar')
b <- a %>% stringr::str_to_lower() %>% strsplit("[[:space:]]")
```

Here `b` is a list of words for every element in `a`. But `b[1]` is also a list. I need `b[1]` to be a character vector

Tried `unlist(b, recursive = FALSE)` . But it is converting `b` to a vector. I just need b to be a flat list with two character vectors 1) "foo" "bar" 2) "foobar"

Comment: `b[1]` will always be a list because of how `[` works.  I think you need `b[[1]]` which is a vector

Comment: So it is already a list with two character vectors?

Comment: yes it is.  type `str(b)` to see

Comment: Thank you so much! Can you please provide an answer for this if possible https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54624609/character-vector-is-being-coerced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`b[1]` is a list because using `[i]` to extract things from a list **always returns a list**; if `i` is a vector of length 1 then you get a list of length 1.  `b[[1]]` returns a character vector as requested.

```
> b[[1]]
[1] "foo" "bar"
> str(b[[1]])
 chr [1:2] "foo" "bar"
```

As Hadley Wickham [posted on twitter](https://twitter.com/hadleywickham/status/643381054758363136):

[image]

Comment: It still gave me a list inside a list. I need to add a line in pipe so that I get character vectors in the list 'b'----"foo" "bar" is a character vector and "foobar" another character vector. So b should contain two character vectors

Comment: Basically I need a flat list with two character vectors