# Character vector is being coerced

Tags: r, string, list, vector

I am doing this simple command where it takes a string "A" and splits it into words using space. Now pipe this vector of words to a replace method where it replaces anything that looks like a complete number to "P12". But the output is getting messy by doing the last operation

```
 A <- list(c("a12, 34, 35, 46"),c("ab14, 44, 55, 66"))
    B <- stringr::str_split(A, "[[:space:]]") %>% str_replace(pattern = "^[:digit:]{1,}[,]{1}$", replacement = "p12")
```

output:

```
[1] "c(\"a12,\", \"34,\", \"35,\", \"46\")"
```

**Updated**: desired output should contain two character vectors stored in a list named B:

```
[1] list(c("a12", "34", "35", "46"), c("ab14", "44", "55", "66"))
```

**This part is answered. Thank you!**
Also please help with regex. When I use the command below, 46 is not being replaced. How should I ensure if 1) the text is a complete number followed by a comma or no comma gets replaced by "p12"

```
str_replace(c("a12,", "34,", "35,", "46"), pattern = "^[:digit:]{1,}[,]{1}$", replacement = "p12")
```

output:

```
"a12," "p12"  "p12"  "46"
```

desired:

```
"a12," "p12"  "p12"  "p12"
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `str_split` returns a `list`, while `str_replace` expects a character vector. Just add `unlist()` in the pipe between `str_split` and `str_replace`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Actually I have a slightly different issue. I modified the question. My output should contain two character vectors stored in a list. Please check the modified question. I need the output in the form list(c("a12", "34", "35", "46"), c("ab14", "44", "55", "66"))

Comment: A looks similar to B.

Comment: No, look at the quotations. In B, split words are stored in a vector. In A, word in combined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str_split` returns a list of character vectors. You just want to `unlist()`. It's not intuitive, but it's so it can handle a character vector input (one list for every element).

Regarding the regex, there isn't a comma on the final number. Try allowing it to match with 0 or 1 commas:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
A <- "a12, 34, 35, 46"
str_split(A, "[[:space:]]") %>% 
  unlist() %>% 
  str_replace(pattern = "^[:digit:]{1,}[,]{0,1}$", replacement = "p12")
```

Output:

```
#[1] "a12," "p12"  "p12"  "p12"
```

Comment: Code golf: you can replace `{0,1}` with `?`. (Ref: https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Actually I have a slightly different issue. I modified the question. My output should contain two character vectors stored in a list. Please check the modified question. I need the output in the form list(c("a12", "34", "35", "46"), c("ab14", "44", "55", "66"))

Answer (score 1):

You can use lapply to do the replacement on each list element.  Your question is a bit unclear (and keeps changing), so I'm not sure whether you want the commas in the output or not.

For solution with commas we can use:

```
str_split(A, "[[:space:]]") %>% 
  lapply(function(x) gsub("\\b\\d+\\b", "p12", x))
# [[1]]
# [1] "a12," "p12," "p12," "p12" 
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "ab14," "p12,"  "p12,"  "p12"
```

Without commas:

```
str_split(A, boundary('word')) %>% 
  lapply(function(x) gsub("\\b\\d+\\b", "p12", x))
# [[1]]
# [1] "a12" "p12" "p12" "p12"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "ab14" "p12"  "p12"  "p12"
```